# $\forall n >3, \quad u_{n+1}=\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{n+1}-2}-u_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We consider the following sequence :

$\forall n >3, \quad u_{n+1}=\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{n+1}-2}-u_n$

What is the asymptotic equivalent of $u_n$ ?

---

My attempt :

- $u_n=f(n)-u_{n-1}$
- $f(n) =n^2/ (\sqrt  {n}-2)=n^{3/2} \dfrac{1}{1-2/\sqrt{n}}= n^{3/2} (1+2/\sqrt{n}+o(1/\sqrt{n}))$
- $f(n)=n^{3/2} +2  n +o(n)$
- $f'(x)=\dfrac{3x^{3/2}-4x}{2 (\sqrt{x}-2)^2}$

We may bound the derivative of $f'$ and then $|f(n)-f(n-1)$ ???

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what were you trying to do in your attempt?

Comment: How much detail do you need for the "asymptotic equivalent"? Since $u_n+u_{n+1}\sim n^{3/2}$, $u_n\sim\tfrac12n^{3/2}$. This already tells us your formula for $f^\prime$ is out by a factor asymptotic to $2$.

Comment: I may have done an error

Comment: Any idea, on how to solve it ?